# Текущее время в Android

Tags: java, android

Я хочу получать реальное время
`DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();`
но создается много объектов обновляя его, а если его не обновлять, то время остается неизменным.

Comment: Для чего оно вам нужно - как планируете использовать?

Comment: Умения две даты нахожу разницу между ними и показываю их на экране в реальном времени , проблема в том что дата не меняется если не получать новый объект = new DateTime(); и у меня все обновляется в Canvas где-то 60 fps получается много объектов 

Comment: @Max Используйте System.currentTimeMillis();

Answer (score 2):

Не создавайте каждый раз новый объект для даты, а обновляйте текущий. Вот пример как это можно сделать с помощью стандартного `java.util.Date`:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date date = new Date(start);
    //будем выводить текущую дату в течение 10 сек с частотой 60fps
    while (date.getTime() < start + 10*1000) {
        date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(date);
        sleep(60);
    }
}

private static void sleep(int fps) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000/ fps);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```